# Authorize Slack bot

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, slack, azure-bot-service

I need to store additional information (teamid, team name, email, etc.) from the user/slack during application authorization/installation.

I did all steps according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs. Most important is "Add a new Redirect Url". I added https://slack.botframework.com.

When I install the application to Slack (from App directory, Slack button), the oauth request is sent to this URL (https://slack.botframework.com) with a temporary authorization code, he exchanges the code for an access token, authorizes the installation, stores the tokes etc. After this, I need to redirect the user to my page and ask him for additional information, and store information like teamid, team name to my database.

I added a Landing Page Url in Slack Channel Registration but doesn't work and after installation, I had been redirected to https://dev.botframework.com/.

I have a solution/idea but I am not sure if the bot framework allows it.

I have my own authorization page instead https://slack.botframework.com. When a user installs the bot to Slack, he is redirected to this page. I exchange the temporary code for an authorization token, I get all the required information from Slack response (teamid, team name), but now I need to store the tokens to Azure bot Service, without this the bot won't work. This is the challenge if I am able to do it with the Bot framework.

Comment: Supposing your own authorization page is nio78.com, have you tried taking the request that Slack sends to nio78.com and redirecting it to slack.botframework.com before or after you do your custom processing?

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. The problem is, how you register the app/bot, if you register the app/bot from Azure portal, it works perfect, if you register the app from Slack, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well done. Please post that as an answer so you can accept it